# what is the summation $\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}j \log j $?

Tags: summation, numerical-methods

I come from Computer Science and I am not good in mathematics and numerical analysis. I proposed a recursive algorithm for a problem whose running time is $$T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n \log n).$$ Clearly its running time is

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}j \log j.
\end{equation}

An obvious upper bound on its running time is $O(n^2\log n)$, I would like to know what exactly the summation 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}j \log j
\end{equation}
is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some superficial observations in case they prove helpful for manual computation: $$ \sum_{j=1}^n = j \log j = \log \prod_{j=1}^n j^j =  \log\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{n!}{j!}= \log\left(\frac{n!}{1!}\cdot\frac{n!}{2!}\cdots\frac{n!}{n!}\right)$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By partial integration,$$\int x\ln x=\frac12x^2\ln x-\int \frac12x^2\frac1x\,\mathrm dx =\frac12x^2\ln x-\frac14x^2+C$$
so that we get 
$$\sum_{j=1}^nj\ln j=\Theta(n^2\ln n),$$
i.e., you cannot reall yimprove upon your obvious upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no closed form but it is asymptotic to $\int_{1}^{n}{x\log x} dx$ which is easy to evaluate